# Is there an upper limit on the number of divs in a document before performance is degraded?

Tags: html, browser

I'm working on a site that will be showing a lot of information via divs. Its basically a chart out of divs. The way its setup is I've got an outer div with a set size that you can scroll the contents around (click and drag like google maps).

From here I can 2 ways of going, have 1 large inner div that is moved around with all the chart divs within it. This would be by far the easiest approach. The other option I see is a tiled approach where I break the large inner div up into smaller divs and dynamically add/remove them as needed.

The chart itself is potentially 1999425014 pixels square. Each point is made up of 6 divs and there are 100,000+ points.

What would be the best way to move forward?

Comment: Use javascript to update the small portion you're actually displaying?

Comment: JavaScript + Canvas may be a better solution if you're charting/graphing data. If your data is tabular, it may or may not be advisable to use tables. You'll have to let us know more details as to what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @zzzzBov:  I would prefer to stay away from the canvas if at all possible. I know it could do what I want, but I'm not looking to go that route right now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529513/javascript-scrolling-issues-dynamically-adding-removing-tiles-using-jquery if you're interested in my current direction and issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most modern browsers render sections of pages only as needed. If the entire page fits in RAM, only the section that is currently visible is being drawn. I conclude this because large documents do not slow down my computer when I use other programs, but there is a bit of lag when I scroll across one. Plus, when the window is repainted through the operating system's APIs, only the pixels that are visible should be rendered. That would only make sense when designing it, anyway.

Surely you can fit as many as you want on a page without worrying about real-time performance hits, unless you're talking about scrolling. Rendering the document should take less time than retrieving it out of system memory and determining where the scroll bars are.

Best of luck, and merry Christmas.

-Tom

Comment: I guess I would be a bit concerned about the RAM usage. I think I'll go with the tiled approach. Thanks